# table size seems high for the amount of records in db

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple table [image]

and I have blanked out the twitterdetail and rawsource and set it as null so there is no data in them, however the space for that table is 350mb.
[image]

There is 67k records so if one does math on the filled fields, it should not be that high.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Its because of the data page files are still there. [John eisbrener](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/39083/john-eisbrener) explained my [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/187565/105575) very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say anything definitive without knowing how the table was defined or what you did to "blank out" the columns, but NULLs still take up space and you still have an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` `MatchedKeywords` column which could be taking up plenty of space.

Sometimes tables can change in size after a `REBUILD`. If you feel that the table is taking up too much space right now I suggest trying that.